# Time arithmetic on pandas series

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a column "StartTime" that could be any datetime value. I would like to create a second column that gives the StartTime relative to the beginning of the week (i.e., 12am on the previous Sunday). For example, this post is 5 days, 14 hours since the beginning of this week.

```
             StartTime
1  2007-01-19 15:59:24
2  2007-03-01 04:16:08
3  2006-11-08 20:47:14
4  2008-09-06 23:57:35
5  2007-02-17 18:57:32
6  2006-12-09 12:30:49
7  2006-11-11 11:21:34
```

I can do this, but it's pretty dang slow:

```
def time_since_week_beg(x):
    y = x.to_datetime()
    return pd.Timedelta(days=y.weekday(),
                        hours=y.hour,
                        minutes=y.minute,
                        seconds=y.second
                       )

df['dt'] = df.StartTime.apply(time_since_week_beg)
```

What I want is something like this, that doesn't result in an error:

```
df['dt'] = pd.Timedelta(days=df.StartTime.dt.dayofweek,
                        hours=df.StartTime.dt.hour,
                        minute=df.StartTime.dt.minute,
                        second=df.StartTime.dt.second
            )

TypeError: Invalid type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. Must be int or float.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
df['dt'] = [pd.Timedelta(days=ts.dayofweek, 
                         hours=ts.hour, 
                         minutes=ts.minute, 
                         seconds=ts.second) 
            for ts in df.StartTime]

>>> df
            StartTime              dt
0 2007-01-19 15:59:24 4 days 15:59:24
1 2007-03-01 04:16:08 3 days 04:16:08
2 2006-11-08 20:47:14 2 days 20:47:14
3 2008-09-06 23:57:35 5 days 23:57:35
4 2007-02-17 18:57:32 5 days 18:57:32
5 2006-12-09 12:30:49 5 days 12:30:49
6 2006-11-11 11:21:34 5 days 11:21:34
```

Depending on the format of `StartTime`, you may need:

```
...for ts in pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime)
```

Comment: This is definitely cleaner. I'm not sure it is faster. Anyway you can think of that can perform operations on the series? Don't know if that will help speed things up or not.

Comment: It probably won't be faster.  `df.StartTime.apply(lambda ts: pd.Timedelta(days=ts.dayofweek, hours=ts.hour, minutes=ts.minute, seconds=ts.second))`

Comment: On 100k rows, timings are virtually identical.